# Using multiple data sources in a scatter graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, csv

I have a script that runs something in a loop and writes its duration into a .csv file on a share. The file looks like this:

```
"timestamp","duration","ComputerName"
"7/8/2014 2:56:03 PM","00:05:03.4625582","PSAGENT-BLD24"
"7/8/2014 3:01:23 PM","00:04:46.3097429","PSAGENT-BLD24"
(many more lines like this get added all the time...)
```

I wrote an Excel worksheet that uses this .csv in a data connection into one "Data" sheet, and created an X-Y (scatter) graph that shows this data - timestamp is X, duration is Y. It works great - I hit "Refresh" and see new data instantly!

Now, I want to take this to the next level: Run the script on several computers (each writing to `ComputerName.csv` on the share), and show all results as multiple series on the same timeline. I know how to create additional data connections and put their data on new sheets. Having done that...

### My question

I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets, each having data-connection-updating timestamp/duration lists. How do I make a single scatter chart, using all timestamps on a single X axis, and the different lists as Y series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can import data from Excel sheets or from the original text files. You can combine multiple sources together using the Append command:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/append-queries-HA104149760.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

If the files already exist in a windows folder, you can import and append them all in a single step:

http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2013/11/26/from-txt-files-to-bi-solution/

Comment: Thanks, PowerQuery appears the right solution for this. However, when using it, I got all the `duration` data in a single column. I'd like to get it all in separate columns, so I can make a scatter chart with different inputs as different data series. How would I do that?

Comment: Excel Charts are not really good at this.  I would use the Power View Add-In which can present a Scatter Chart using a Field (e.g. ComputerName) to set the Color, which splits the data into series.

Comment: I couldn't get PowerView to show my data as a chart (don't know why). I ended up using the merged PowerQuery table, and creating a table with my own columns from it.

Comment: Power View has this odd restriction where you have to define a Summary setting for a numeric column (via Power Pivot) before it will let you chart your data.  Otherwise it only shows tables.